# Why Bearer Token not working on my server?

Tags: laravel, bearer-token

I have a problem with authentication. My Laravel 7 project uses a Bearer Token. On localhost it works fine. But on production server **$user = auth('api')->user();** returns null.

My step 1: login to the server and get the token (success on localhost and production) via Postman.
My step 2: Input token in Bearer Token field in Postman
My step 3: Send some GET request to the server with Bearer Token. On localhost - OK, on production - "user not found".

Code on localhost and server is same. What is difference between localhost and server?

Comment: The request to create the bearer token only exists locally,   so you need to "create a new bearer token" on the server and use that for server requests. Are you using a framework like passport or sanctum ?

Comment: Yes, laravel/passport is used. The production and localhost databases are the same. There in oauth_clients are 2 entries  ("Laravel Personal Access Client" and "Laravel Password Grant Client"). The php artisan passport:keys command returns "Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them". I've read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport but couldn't figure out what else I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. The problem was that the server was not accepting the Authorization header. To solve the problem, I added the following lines to the .htaccessfile:

```
#Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```